# Is there an R function checks dates for previous rows?

Tags: r, date

I have a data set that contains transactional data for stores in the last 2 years. The data is arranged by outlet and product. I am trying to compare current revenue against the average revenue of the last 3 months. Where there is just one/two transactions in the last 3 months, I want R to return the average of those one/two months and where there is no transactions in the last 3 months, I want R to return 0. I also would like to have the same measures for the prior year. I have tired rollmean from the zoo package, but it returns values which I can't explain with a simple calculator.

Data looks like this

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Comment: Rather than adding input as images, add it as actual data. For example using `dput(data)` (changing `data` for your data). This allows us to "copy/paste" rather than having to "type" manually and increases your chances of receiving a good answer

Comment: Thanks Oliver. This is my first ever post here and I'll do better next time.

Comment: No worries. You can edit your post to include the data necessary. Basically if you have your data in R (matrix, data.frame or similar)  you just run `dput` and it outputs a long string that you can copy into your post. It'll likely get an answer quickly once the data is avaialble.